# Trying to pass a parameter to a new EventHandler

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, webview2

I am using the new `WebView2` to insert text into a textbox within Edge. I have the event below:

```
webView.NavigationCompleted += new EventHandler<CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs>(InputText);
```

It runs the following code:

```
private async void InputText(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('Textbox').value = 'Test';");
}
```

This works for the test site I am playing with. However, I want to pass the script as a string variable into the `InputText` method. Trying to add it to it states, that there is no overload for the delegate such as:

```
webView.NavigationCompleted += new EventHandler<CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs>(e => InputText(this, e, "Test"));

private async void InputText(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args, string test)
{
    await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('Textbox').value = 'Test';");
}
```

Is there a way to overload this to add a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EventHandler<CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs>` delegate has signature that delares a parameter `sender` of type `object` and `e` of type `CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs`.

```
public delegate void EventHandler<CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs>(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e);
```

However, the lambda expression `e => InputText(this, e, "Test")` has only one parameter `e`. You need to add a second parameter for `sender` to match the delegate signature above. Let's call it `s`.

```
(s, e) => InputText(this, e, "Test")
```

If you do not use the parameter anyway, you can also ignore it explicitly with the discard operator.

```
(_, e) => InputText(this, e, "Test")
```

Please also make sure that your `test` parameter is used in your method. Here I use string interpolation with `$` to insert the value of `test` into your script.

```
private async void InputText(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args, string test)
{
    await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('Textbox').value = '{test}';");
}
```